# Google Maps Geocoding API, feature from the API missing in their JS api (?)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

The problem is simple, in the documentation for the Geocoding API they say component filtering exists. (Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

However, if I look at the JS documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding), it doesn't seem to be implemented. I do however remember that google earlier used to have features implemented but not written about in their API, so I wonder if anyone knows how to achieve component filtering with the Google Maps Geocoding API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation seems to of implemented it now. Either way, here is the code:

```
geocoder.geocode( 
      { 'address': address, 'componentRestrictions':{'country':'GB'}}, 
function(results, status){
...   
});
```

> Used to restrict results to a specific area. A filter consists of one
>   or more of: route, locality, administrativeArea, postalCode or
>   country. Only the results that match all the filters will be returned.
>   Filter values support the same methods of spelling correction and
>   partial matching as other geocoding requests. See Component Filtering
>   in the Geocoding web service for further details.