# Restricting geocoding to a country

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I have seen that it is possible with the "static" to limit the scope of the search to a certain area (with components restrictions), I have also seen that in release 3.exp (will be 3.14) of the JavaScript API, a new class google.maps.GeocoderComponentRestrictions has appeared. I have not seen anywhere how this class is supposed to be used though.
Does anyone have more information about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this was answered over at [Google Maps Geocoding API, feature from the API missing in their JS api (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201535/google-maps-geocoding-api-feature-from-the-api-missing-in-their-js-api/18146563#18146563), with formatting like:

```
geocoder.geocode( 
      { 'address': address, 'componentRestrictions':{'country':'GB'}}, 
function(results, status){
...   
});
```

The `GeocoderComponentRestrictions` parameters get passed with the `componentRestrictions` key.