# Google map auto complete component filtering

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui, google-maps, geocoding

How do I use use component filtering in geocoding when used with jquery ui auto complete

```
$("#address").autocomplete({
    //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
    source: function(request, response) { 

        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {

                    response($.map(results, function(item) {

                        return {
                           label:  item.formatted_address,
                            value: item.formatted_address,
                            latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                            longitude: item.geometry.location.lng(),
                            loc :item.formatted_address   
                        }
                    }));
                })


    })
})
```

I want component filtering like this http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=santa+cruz&components=country:ES&sensor=false

Comment: i think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17201535/google-maps-geocoding-api-feature-from-the-api-missing-in-their-js-api

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Google's Places Autocomplete library...(since you want to have autocomplete after geocoding )

```
var autoCompleteOptions = {
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'} //any country you want
    };

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('#address')[0], autoCompleteOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work for you hopefully ..

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term ,components=country:ES},
```